Why GCP Cloud Run not use the Compute Engine SA to authenticate while using Python pub/sub library?
I am trying to publish message to a pubsub topic from cloud run using Python library. I have granted pubsub admin role to the Compute Engine Service Account and through gcloud command, I am able to publish messages to the pubsub topic. However, if I try to make use of python pubsub library, it throws exception with message:
File ./service-account-key.json was not found.

Below is the code:
os.system('gcloud pubsub topics publish pubsub-test1 --message="test" --project=project1')
credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
publisher_audience = "https://pubsub.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.Publisher"
credentials_pub = credentials.with_claims(audience=publisher_audience)
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(credentials=credentials_pub)

reference

Various authentication methods are available from the google-auth library  and refer to this documentation setup authentication.
To Set up ADC with the credentials that are associated with your Google Account. After you install and initialize the gcloud CLI, configure ADC using:
gcloud auth application-default login


A sign-in screen appears. After you sign in, your credentials are stored in the local credential file used by ADC.

Use the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to provide the location of a credential JSON file within your GCP project.


For more information, see Set up Application Default Credentials.

I am trying to login using python library and not through cli. What is the python API for login using the cloud run Service account without explicitly specifying json file ?

below is the call equivalent of
gcloud auth application-default login

credentials_new = compute_engine.Credentials()

